How can i set the scm publishing and ftp in an Azure function App using azure cli?
I want to set the SCM and FTP on my Azure function app using  azure cli.
I have tried the following
 az functionapp config set --name $FUNCTION_APP_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP  --ftp-publishing-enabled true

az functionapp config set --name $FUNCTION_APP_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP  --scm-publishing-enabled true
But says that --ftp-publishing-enabled and --scm-publishing-enabled are unrecognized arguments.
How can i set these values ?

Have you got any error?

I have created the Consumption Model Azure Function App where these are the settings related to SCM and FTP came as default:

SCM: Off
FTP State: FTPS Only


To change these settings using Azure CLI, below are the commands and its execution:
FTP Setting:
az webapp config set --name <app-name> --resource-group <group-name> --ftps-state FtpsOnly

Possible values for –ftps-state are:

AllAllowed (FTP and FTPS enabled),
Disabled (FTP and FTPs disabled), and
FtpsOnly (FTPS only).


SCM Setting:
az resource update --resource-group dkamaxxxx --name scm --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies --parent sites/fapp-cons-dkam-si-01 --set properties.allow=false


For your reference: MS Doc on Azure CLI Commands for FTP Setting and SCM Setting.
Result:

